# How do I make this code function correctly?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I want to make a sort of Lobby system in Roblox Studio where if you have 4 people on a part you get sent to another place. I tried to set up a system for it, but it didn't work; can you help me through this?

I've tried making it so it says .Value at the end.

```lua
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")

player_amount = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Player_Count
local placeID_1 = 4119652438
local function onPartTouch(otherPart)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
    if player then 
        player_amount.Value = player_amount.Value + 1
    end
    if player_amount == 4 then
        TeleportService:Teleport(placeID_1, player)
    end
end


script.Parent.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

I expected the output to be 0 then if one person steps on it, it would update the sign to say 1. But it only stays at 0.

Comment: It looks to me like you are increasing the value of an IntValue or something similar. If you want the sign to change you are better referencing the text with `.Text = etc...`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a viable solution as .Touched fires every frame the player touches a part, and only when they move. I suggest creating a hitbox, as I have done [here](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/detecting-on-which-map-the-character-is/233463/13)